# Does cutting/concatting of MP4 keep keyframes of scenes?

Tags: format, mp4, video-processing

I wonder if keyframes stay 100% the same (so they could be hashed and used as an identifier for that scene) if a video editor would "cut" or "concat" multiple scenes in two cases:
a) he has source materials and creates two variants (e.g. different length of scenes)
b) he re-uses webencoded video scenes (e.g. just cuts a part from a longer video or merge multiple short clips to one lengthy one)

Any input welcome - thanks

Comment: don't you think that this might depend on the software?

Comment: Yupp, that could easily be. Maybe somebody knows.